# Failed to downgrade from Yarn 3.x to 1.x

Tags: yarnpkg

I updated to Yarn 3.x recently and I can't really do anything with Yarn because the strange errors am getting, so I have decided to downgrade to 1.x, but it has failed to install back to 1.x

I ran `yarn set version v1.22.19`. Can someone help me with what I should do?

Below is the error I am getting:

```
coder@jessie:~$ yarn set version v1.22.19
➤ YN0000: Retrieving https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/download/vv1.22.19/yarn-v1.22.19.js
➤ YN0035: The remote server failed to provide the requested resource
➤ YN0035:   Response Code: 404 (Not Found)
➤ YN0035:   Request Method: GET
➤ YN0035:   Request URL: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/download/vv1.22.19/yarn-v1.22.19.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not previous the version with `v`.
(Notice the double `vv` in the download URL `➤ YN0000: Retrieving https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/download/vv1.22.19`)

`yarn set version 1.22.19` should work